# Subir tabela HTML utilizando CSS

Tags: html, css

Quero subir uma tabela HTML e deixá-la na mesma altura que o formulário à esquerda dela, já tentei com de várias maneiras(top, vertical-align, etc), porém sem resultado.

[image]

```css
body {
  background: #d6d6f5;
  padding-left: 4%;
}

.caixa {
  width: 40%;
  background: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 20px solid #d6d6f5;
  border-radius: 1px;
  vertical-align: left;
}

.divtabela {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tabela {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Cadastro de clientes</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF= "imgs/icone.png"  type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

</head>
    <input type="button" class="voltar" value="←"  onclick=" return BackToComMenu()">

<body>
    <div class="caixa">
    <center><img id="logo" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="Logo da FullTime"></center>



    <main>
        <form action="php/cadastrar.php" method="POST" id="FormCadastro">

            <p>Cadastro de Clientes</p>             

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
              <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
              <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
              <input name="email" type="text"  placeholder="Email" onclick="return checarEmail()" >
              <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
                <input name="telefone" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="11">
                <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
              </div>

            <div class="inputWithIcon">
              <input name="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)">
              <i class="fa fa-address-card   fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
            </div>


            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="enviar" onclick="return cadastrar()">

            </div>


            <div class="divtabela">     
                <table class="tabela">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th >Email <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw"></i></th>
                            <th >CPF <i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-lg fa-fw"></i></th>


                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <tr>

                            <td>Teste1</td>
                        <td>000.000.000-00</td>

                      </tr>
                      <tr>

                        <td>Teste2</td>
                        <td>999.999.999-99</td>
                        </tr>   
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Você quer deixar a tabela do mesmo tamanho que o formulário ou subir a tabela e deixá-la alinha acima? o título da sua pergunta e a descrição dizem coisas diferentes.

Comment: Quero alinhar a tabela para cima de forma que fique na mesma altura que o formulário.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois atributos que em conjunto permitem que você mova algum item utilizando o plano cartesiano. São eles o position e o transform. rodei o código na máquina e na tabela deixei da seguinte forma:

```
.divtabela {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 transform: translateY(-140%);


}
```

O `position: relative;` "relativiza" a posição em relação a disposição das informações na tela (sua posição inicial), permitindo que você aplique outros atrbutos de movimento.
Já o  `transform: translateY(-140%);` serve para "transformar" isto é, mudar sua posição em relação a antiga. (repare que na sintaxe estou utilizando translateY, para dizer que minha mudança seja feita no eixo y, e a porcentagem a ser aplicada depende do quão acima (ou abaixo) você quer. (transform também aceita pixels)

Comment: Perfeito, pois dessa forma eu pude escolher com precisão o alinhamento desejado. Obrigadoooo!!!

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso como vc colocou `display-inline-block` nos elementos eles assume um escopo híbrido entre `block/inline` e vc pode usar a propriedade de alinhamento `inline` `vertical-align` para alinhar a "tabela" no topo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima.

**OBS:** Seu código tem tags fechadas erras, e no CSS vc colocou `vertical-align: left;` se e **vertical** como pode ser `left`?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<title>Cadastro de clientes</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link REL="SHORTCUT ICON" HREF="imgs/icone.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<style>
  body {
    background: #d6d6f5;
    padding-left: 4%;
  }

  .caixa {
    width: 40%;
    background: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 20px solid #d6d6f5;
    border-radius: 1px;
    vertical-align: left;
  }

  .divtabela {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    
        vertical-align: top;
  }

  .tabela {
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 200%;
    margin-left: 80px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<input type="button" class="voltar" value="←" onclick=" return BackToComMenu()">

<body>
  <div class="caixa">
    <center><img id="logo" src="imgs/logo.png" alt="Logo da FullTime"></center>



    <main>
      <form action="php/cadastrar.php" method="POST" id="FormCadastro">

        <p>Cadastro de Clientes</p>

        <div class="inputWithIcon">
          <input name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome">
          <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="inputWithIcon">
          <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" onclick="return checarEmail()">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="inputWithIcon">
          <input name="telefone" type="text" placeholder="Telefone" maxlength="11">
          <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="inputWithIcon">
          <input name="cpf" type="text" placeholder="CPF" maxlength="14" OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)">
          <i class="fa fa-address-card   fa-lg fa-fw" aria-hidden="true" name="user"></i>
        </div>


        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="enviar" onclick="return cadastrar()">

  </div>


  <div class="divtabela">
    <table class="tabela">
      <thead>
        <tr>

          <th>Email <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg fa-fw"></i></th>
          <th>CPF <i class="fa fa-credit-card fa-lg fa-fw"></i></th>


        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td>Teste1</td>
          <td>000.000.000-00</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

          <td>Teste2</td>
          <td>999.999.999-99</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  </form>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl, o vertical align deu certo mesmo, entretanto, não alinhado com a caixa ao lado. De qualquer forma eu não estava conseguindo nem isso, acho que estava colocando tal style na class .tabela, e não na .divtabela como você fez. Sobre as tags fechadas, infelizmente não consegui identificá-las kk, mas vou me esforçar para que isso não aconteça novamente.

Comment: Para o vertical-align: left não há nem desculpa, certo? Pura desatenção kkk

Comment: @JonatanRocha tranquilo meu caro! Continue com os estudos []´s

Comment: Obrigado !! pode deixar